# Yum error when trying to install remi repo

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rpm

New installation of CentOS 7.2 with Apache 2.4.6. Trying to install the remi repo so that I can upgrade to PHP 5.6 (yum only provides 5.4). When trying to install the repo from an rpm, I get the following error:

```
rpm -Uvh remi-release-7*.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
yum is needed by remi-release-7.1-3.el7.remi.noarch
```

Obviously, I have yum, so I don't know what the problem is. I've never seen this before when trying to install a repo. EPEL came over fine.

Comment: `yum clean all`    Then try removing that '*' asterisk in the `rpm -Uvh remi-release-7*.rpm`    There is also the `yum localinstall remi-release-7.rpm` option.

Comment: About `yum localinstall`  : Today this will do : `# cd Downloads/ && yum install [package(s).rpm]`

Answer (score 0):

You can install the RPM with yum:

`sudo yum localinstall remi-release-7*.rpm`